# Ansible wait for reboot

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I'm kickstarting a server using a playbook that contains the following wait snippet for booting:

```
-name: Wait until boot complete
 pause: minutes=30
```

When 30 minutes are over, there is process that reboots the server one more time(at about 45 mins from the boot start), causing the next task to fail due to the server being unreachable. As a temporary measure, I changed the wait interval to 60 minutes and the playbook runs successfully. Is there any other way I could check if the second server reboot is complete so that the next task can run as soon possible and not wait for 60 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

The [reboot module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/reboot_module.html) is designed for exactly this.  Create a task that invokes module `reboot`, and your remote system will reboot and your play will continue when the system is connectable again.
You can provide an optional `reboot_timeout` argument to the module.

Comment: Kickstart takes about 30 mins, and then some processes run and about 45 mins from the start of the rekick, the server reboots again. If I use the reboot module, it will explicitly reboot the server, but if the explicit reboot intersects with the kickstart reboot, the playbook will fail. Is there a way to map if there is a process that is currently rebooting in ansible?